# ¿Cómo puedo sumar filas iguales en dplyr para que solo aparezcan las sumas en las columnas?

Tags: r, rstudio, r-dplyr

Muy buen día.

Estoy buscando sumar las mismas filas en un data frame.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pueden ver, estoy buscando hacer los totales por folio sin mover las columnas de las variables que tenemos. Es decir, el folio "1121" se repite varias veces en el data frame, y necesito el total de las ventas del folio 1121, y así con todas las variables y con todos los folios, para concluir vaciando los resultados en otro data frame.

Para que al final, el data frame generado quede con este estilo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema es que no se como estructurar el codigo con DPLYR, estuve pensando en hacerlo con el verbo "summarise".

```
ventas<- data.frame(folio=c(01121, 01122,01123,01121,01124,01125,01121,01123,01125,01123,01124,01121,01126,01121,01123,01124,01122,01124,01123,01121,01123,01127,01124,01121,01121,01123,01124,01123,01121,01126,01128,01121,01125,01123,01124,01121,01129,01126,01125,01124), venta=c(50,100,50,42,14,16,16,15,20,17,19,60,14,400,15,17,12,60,14,20,14,18,16,25,14,35,65,47,89,54,54,58,20,14,12,03,14,16,25,82), impu=c(2,1,3,6,4,5,8,9,4,6,2,5,8,7,1,2,3,1,5,5,1,4,1,6,3,5,9,8,7,2,6,3,5,4,1,5,6,9,8,3), vala=c(87,64,51,14,17,18,19,14,14,15,16,1,5,2,1,4,7,8,9,6,3,2,5,8,9,6,4,7,5,8,6,2,1,4,5,6,8,9,7,4), plan=c(0,0,0,0,0,1,0,2,1,3,1,2,3,1,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,3,0,1,2,4,0,1,4,1,5,0,1,2,3))
```

Les agradezco mucho su tiempo y su respuesta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Efectivamente el "verbo" es `summarise`:

```
library(tidyverse)

ventas %>% 
    group_by(folio) %>%                 # Agrupamos por folio
    summarise(venta = sum(venta),       # Sumamos venta
              impu = n_distinct(impu),  # contamos distintos
              vala = n_distinct(vala),  # contamos distintos
              plan = n_distinct(plan)   # contamos distintos
    )
```

Luego de agrupar por `folio` simplemente sumamos `venta` dentro del `summarise`, desconozco que función de agregación, necesitas para el resto de las columnas, así que el ejemplo apunta a contar los valores distintos en cada grupo con `n_distinct()`

Comment: Muchísimas gracias Patricio, es lo que necesitaba.